# While Entering Numerical Values in Edittext how to check for Pattern ##.### whille Typing

Tags: java, android

```
mPattern = Pattern.compile("([1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,2}([0-9]{3})*(\\.[0-9]{0,2})?
                            |[1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,}(\\.[0-9]{0,2})?|0(\\.[0-9]{0,2})? 
                            |(\\.[0-9]{1,2})?)");
```

above is the pattern but its not properly checking the values in edittext while entering the value.

can anyone help me

to validate inputs like this

```
12.325
95.365
85.665
87.256
```

Comment: So, is your problem that the regex is wrong? It seems very overcomplicated, can you show us a few examples of what should be allowed and what shouldn't be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell from your regex, you want to allow 1-3 digits, followed by an optional `.` followed by 1-3 digits. Also, you seem to want to allow the forms `0.##`, and `.###`. This validates those specifications:

```
mPattern = Pattern.compile("[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(\\.[0-9]{1,3})?|0?\\.[0-9]{1,3}");
```